# MVC - Joining multiple table using LINQ / lambda - Using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am implementing a controller and I need to get all staff members which have a certain RiskTypeID, which will be selected by the user when they click on Navigation Item.

Here is how I would create the joins in SQL

**SQL**

```
Select 
RTHG.RiskTypeID,
SM.FullName

From RiskTypeHasGroup RTHG
Inner join RiskGroup RG On RTHG.RiskGroupID = RG.ID
Inner join RiskGroupHasGroupMembers RGHGM ON RG.ID = RGHGM.RiskGroupID
Inner Join GroupMember GM ON RGHGM.GroupMemberID = GM.ID
Inner Join GroupMemberHasStaffMember GMHSM ON GM.ID = GMHSM.GroupMemberID
Inner Join StaffMember SM ON GMHSM.StaffMemberID = SM.ID

Where RTHG.RiskTypeID = 1
```

I’ve pulled back data before using Linq and lambda but only using simple expressions, I now need to be able to make a call which will bring back the same data as the sql outlined above, I’ve searched online but can’t find anything similar to my requirement.

Here is my Controller, I placed comments inside as guidance

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ViewRiskTypes(int SelectedRiskTypeID)
{
    var RiskTypes = _DBContext.RiskTypes.ToList(); // Get all of the current items held in RiskTypes tables, store them as a List in Var RiskTypes
    var ViewModel = new List<RiskTypeWithDetails>(); // Create colletion which holds instances of RiskTypeWithDetails and pass them to the ViewModel
    var Details = new RiskTypeWithDetails(); // Create a new instance of RiskType with details and store the instance in var Details

    foreach (var RiskType in RiskTypes) // Loop through each Item held in var RiskTypes
    {
        Details.RiskTypes.Add(new RiskTypesItem { ID = RiskType.ID, Description = RiskType.Description }); // assign each items ID & Description to the same feilds in a new
        // instance of RiskTypeItems (which is a property of RiskTypeWithDetails)
    }

    foreach (var RiskType in RiskTypes)  // Loop through each item in RiskTypes
    {
        if (RiskType.ID == SelectedRiskTypeID) // Check Item ID matches SelectedRiskTypeID value
        {
            //var Details = new RiskTypeWithDetails();
            Details.RiskTypeDescription = RiskType.Description;  //assign the Risk type Descripton to RiskTypeWithDetails RiskTypeDescription Property
            Details.RiskDetails = _DBContext
                .RiskTypeHasGroups
                //.GroupMemberTypeHasGroupMembers
                .Where(r => r.RiskTypeID == SelectedRiskTypeID) // Where RiskTypeId matches Selected ID bring back following data from Db
                .Select(r => new RiskDetails
                {
                    RiskGroupDescription = r.RiskGroup.Description,
                    GroupMembers = r.RiskGroup.RiskGroupHasGroupMembers
                            .Select(v => v.GroupMember).ToList(),
                    //StaffMembers = r.RiskGroup.RiskTypeHasGroups
                    //              .Join(r.RiskGroup.RiskTypeHasGroups,
                    //              a => a.RiskGroupID , b => b.RiskGroup.ID,
                    //              (a, b) => new {a, b})
                    //              .Join(r.RiskGroup.RiskGroupHasGroupMembers,
                    //              c => c.) // Dosent join as I would expect... no idea what to do here
                }).ToList();

            ViewModel.Add(Details); //Add all data retrieved to the ViewModel (This creates one item in the collection)
        }
    }
    return View(ViewModel);
}
```

As you will see I want to get all Staff Members with a match for the selected RiskTypeID. I need some assistance in converting the above SQL to work within my controller as a lambda expression

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a deep graph, but if your relationships are properly configured, you should be able to do something like _db.RTHG.Include(r => r.RG.Select(rg => rg.RGHGM.GM.Select(hm => hm.GMHSM.SM))).Select(new { RTHG.RiskTypeID, SM.FullName }).Where(RTHG.RiskTypeID = 1).ToList();   I abbreviated the table names. See the remarks under the Include statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried to implement this and similar, I still hit a dead end when trying to use include or Select no matter what way I go about it. It seems that because I have this statement nested in a parent Select statement it wont allow me to get to the desired tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with your commented out code! For starters, LINQ has two different sytaxes: `query` and `method chain`. You were using the `method chain` syntax and it can get really unmaintainable really quickly.

For an instance like this, `query` syntax is where it's at.

Here's the result:

```
from rhtg in _dbContext.RiskTypeHasGroup

where rhtg.RiskTypeID == 1

join rg in _dbContext.RiskGroup 
  on rhtg.RiskGroupID equals rg.ID

join rghgm in _dbContext.RiskGroupHasGroupMembers 
  on rg.ID equals rhtg.ID

join gm in _dbContext.GroupMember
  on rg.ID equals gm.ID

join gmhsm in _dbContext.GroupMemberHasStaffMember
  on gm.ID equals gmhsm.GroupMemberID

join sm in _dbContext.StaffMember 
  on gmhsm.StaffMemberID equals sm.ID

select new 
{
  rhtg.RiskTypeId,
  sm.FullName 
};
```

Do note, that I used .Net conventions for the different variables.

Here's some documentation on the `query` syntax:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the differences, yes it was getting really difficult, what ever I tried to do would result in some sort of error. having it nested inside a select statement seems to be causing issues in terms of what tables I can access. I will give this syntax go, am using linq pad for testing.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, I've been working on other things, and just back to   this. I've implemented the above and it got me the data I needed. The only issue I now have is that it's returning an anonymous type.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the exact same query in linq as follows:

```
var query = (from RTHG in _DBContext.RiskTypeHasGroup RTHG
            join RG in _DBContext.RiskGroup on RTHG.RiskGroupID equals RG.ID
            join RGHGM in _DBContext.RiskGroupHasGroupMembers on RG.ID equals RGHGM.RiskGroupID
            join GM in _DBContext.GroupMember on RGHGM.GroupMemberID = GM.ID
            join GMHSM in _DBContext.GroupMemberHasStaffMember on GM.ID equals GMHSM.GroupMemberID
            join SM in _DBContext.StaffMember on GMHSM.StaffMemberID equals SM.ID
        where RTHG.RiskTypeID == 1
        select new {RTHG.RiskTypeID,SM.FullName});
```

Comment: I have copied this using the SQL query that's why you will need to change _DBContext.RiskTypeHasGroup to whatever entity class name you have in your model. I have enclosed the code in () with semi colon in the end for syntax. Try now

Comment: have u included System.Linq in your class ? Sorry i have corrected = to equals in join and = in where to == ... are you still having issues ?